# To check for Substring in two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have joined two tables and need to check for substring that should be present in one column and not in other. I am able to use LIKE operator to find the substring in one column but the operator NOT LIKE isn't working for the other.

Basically the columns contain English text in one and translated text in another. I am trying to find rows in which english letters are translated. ex: A person moved from point A to point B. Here all the words should be translated except for letters A and B.

Here is the query

```
select a.*,b.*
from ot_document_sentence as a
inner join ot_document_sentence_lang as b on b.document_id = a.document_id 
where 
a.sentence_text LIKE '% B %' or '% C %' or '% D %' or .....
and 
b.translated_text NOT LIKE '% B %' or '% C %' or '% D %' or '% E %' or .....
```

The query outputs sentences which has single letters but doesn't filter for translated text which doesn't have English letters.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have provided an answer in the same cryptic format as the question. For a less cryptic response, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *but the operator NOT LIKE isn't working for the other.* This is impossible. It works as you write which simply may differ from what you want...

Comment: I have added problem  description and query as advised.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out the IN clause.